# Database: Storing multiple Types in single table or multiple intermediate delta tables

Tags: oracle, database-design, audit

Using Java and Oracle.

We need to update changes in Email, UserID of employee to third party. 
Actual table is Employee and intermediate table we keep which we will use for comparison of changes before sending to third party.

Following are database designs coming in mind for intermediate table:

Only Single table:

```
EmployeeiD|Value|Type|UpdateDate
```

`Value` is userid or email, `type` will be `'email'` or `'userid'`. Update date is kept so to figure out that which of email or userid was different and update to third party.

Multiple Table:

```
 Employee_EmailID
      EmpId|EmailID|Updatedate

 Employee_UserID
      EmpId|UserID|Updatedate
```

Java flow will be:
 - Pick employee from actual table. 
 - Pick employee from above intermediate table. 
 - Compare differences. Update difference to third party. 
 - Update above table with updated value and last update date.

Which one is consider as best way, single table approach or multiple table or is there any standard way to implement the same? There are 10,000 Employees in system.
Also consider approach when 10 intermediate tables are required like phonenumber, salary etc.

Answer (score 0):

For  the employee table you should have two audit tables.

> 1 employee_audit (employee_audit_id , ref_employee_id, reason,update_date, update_by)

and

> 2 employee_audit_detail (id,ref_employee_audit_id , field_name, old_value)

So you have every value saved only once and you have a complete record,what was changed and by whom grouped the date it was change.

Programming is every time you save data for an employee , you save first a new row in employee_audit  get the last id and then enter a new row for every changed value the name of the value and old  content